# How to create a local react library project with common components, and import that project locally

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to setup a `commonreact` react project. I ran `create-react-app`, then I have created the src folder, under which I have a subfolder `container`. In that I have the file `DefaultEnums.js`

```
import React from 'react'

const IS_RECORD_ACTIVE = {     
    UNKNOWN:"UNKNOWN", 
    UNSPECIFIED:"UNSPECIFIED", 
    Active:"Active",
    Inactive:"Inactive",
    Draft:"Draft", 
    Publish:"Publish", 
    Unpublish:"Unpublish" 
}

export default IS_RECORD_ACTIVE ;
```

Now I have setup another react project `my-project_A` and `my-project_B`. I want to use `IS_RECORD_ACTIVE` in both the two projects. How can I do it ?

I need to some how import `commonreact` in my other projects and then use the variable.

I am learning React, hence the silly question.

Comment: CRA is not for building a component library, set up a build script with e.g. rollup for that one. Then yarn/npm link that library into the CRA app for local dev. If you have the library one running in watch mode it will pick up changes.

Comment: I'd suggest you use _Lerna_ (monorepo) https://github.com/lerna/lerna It'll help you manage your packages versions easily and synchronise the updates you make between a package you just updated and another one which is consuming it, it's very powerful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to create a module then import it in your projects **by linking the module with every project**.

**A] Create the module**

1. create a directory: `my_module`
2. go inside the created directory: `cd my_module`
3. covert this directory to a node module: `npm init`
4. if you don't have [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) installed, install it:

   ```sh
   curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
   echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
       sudo apt update
       sudo apt install yarn
   ```
5. add dependencies:

   ```sh
   yarn add @babel/cli @babel/core
   yarn add @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
   touch .babelrc
   ```
6. add presets to the *.babelrc* file:

   ```json
   {
     "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
   }
   ```
7. make a source directory:

   ```sh
   mkdir src
   cd src
   touch index.js
   ```
8. inside *src/index.js* add any code you want...

   ```
   import React from 'react';

   const DummyComponent = () => (
     <div>This is my module </div>
   )

   export default DummyComponent;
   ```
9. make first build:

   ```sh
   cd ..
   ./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-file index.js
   ```
10. add the build command to *package.json*, so you don’t have to type it again and again:

    ```json
    {
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel src --out-file index.js"
      },
    }
    ```

    **Note: whenever you want to transpile your component you can simply run**: `yarn build`
11. add react & react-dom as peerDependencies. So, inside the package.json, before "devDependencies" add:

    ```
    "peerDependencies": {
      "react": "^16.6.1",
      "react-dom": "^16.6.3" },
    ```
12. now install react & react-dom: `yarn add react react-dom`
13. get the path of your module (do: `pwd`). This command will return the module path, something like '/home/user_name/..../my_module'

**B] Create your ReactJS application that you want to use the module:**

14. do `cd ..`
15. check out if you have nodejs installed (you need: Node ^10.12.0 || >=12.0.0 or higher): `npm current node -v`

If you have problems with node, do: `sudo mv /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node.save`

16. Create a ReactJS application: `yarn create my-project_A`
17. go into the new created project: `cd my-project_A`
18. add your module (the path you got from step 13): `yarn add my_module_path`
19. do: `yarn start`

> 20. import the module inside the App.js:

```
  import MyModule from 'my_module'  
  function App() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <MyModule />
      </div>
    );
  }    
export default App;
```

Comment: I'll try this out and report back. Thanks a ton

Comment: @Ahmad, Can you please create a minimal example on plunker/Stackblitz as it will be useful for wider audiences. This will be helpful.

Comment: @Manzer, I will do it as soon as possible. I will keep you in touch. Thank you!